# Click event and class switch on a random item

Tags: javascript

It is necessary to implement the following functional - by onclick on the button (about-btn) a class should be added (about-item-img-active) to the random element (about-item-img):

```
window.onload = function() {

    var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.about-btn');
    var div = document.querySelectorAll('.about-item-img');
    var rand = mtRand(0, div.length - 1);

    for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
        btn[i].onclick = activeItem.call(div[rand]);
    }

    function activeItem() {
        this.classList.toggle('about-item-img-active');
    }

}

function mtRand(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
```

Help correct or change code.

Comment: Can you tell us what is wrong with the code?  Is your computer exploding? Are you getting an error message? We need details.

Comment: This code does not work, console clear. If you take .onclick = activeItem.call(div[rand]) out of the cycle, works when window onload. Need to click on class '.about-btn' to force to work...